# I don't get this Boolean logic

Tags: python, list, python-requests, boolean, boolean-logic

```
a = [0,0,0]
Print (not a)
```

> Output:

> False

> I don't get it.it's actually >"true" right?.I'm sorry,I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

See, if the list is empty ,then you will get a `True` result.

```py
In [1]: a=[]

In [2]: not a
Out[2]: True
```

So, when you are trying to perform operation on a list object, it will check if the list is `None` or not and then give the result.

```py
In [3]: a=[0]

In [4]: not a
Out[4]: False
```

This will return False because list is not empty. You should read more on python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) or learn from some tutorials. There are plenty available online.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `None`.